# Check if the story points changed in Azure DevOps Boards

Tags: azure-devops, agile, estimation, azure-boards, planning

My goal is to check which, if any, stories had the story point field changed and the values, from old value to new value.

In Queries you can only check the current value for story point, although if you change the story point you can see that in the user story history.

I'm using the Agile process. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straight forward way to do that.

A good approach would be using API:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP

1.Create a work item rule to set the update date:

[image]

2.When defining a new value for the Story Points, set the current time:

[image]

3.Using query with date, get the work item ID:

[image]

4.GET `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates?api-version=5.1`

You could get the history of the old value and new value, and the updated time from the API response.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a mil for your answer. This helped me build a slightly different solution using a rule with an action to "Copy the value from ..." to a new field I created as Original Story Points.